# Make mathematical sense of the Dirac well Potential Equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, quantum-mechanics

A classical problem in quantum mechanics involving the Dirac Delta function is given by
$$
y''+(\delta(x)-\lambda^2)y=0
$$ 
Then, to find ''bound states'', you solve on the right and find the converging solution as $x\rightarrow \infty$, then solve on the left similarly. Assume continuity of the solution $y$. The jump condition on $y'$ is found by integrating from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$   and take $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. The only value of $\lambda$ giving a bound state is then found to be $1/2$.

My issue with this is that to make this solution mathematically correct, one has to make sense of the multiplication of a continuous non-differentiable function by the delta Dirac function. In a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317882/multiplication-of-a-distribution-by-a-continuous-function) of mine, Alan U. Kennington suggested to use Radon measures. However, there must be something simpler that makes sense of the problem above by mathematically making sense of multiplying a continuous function by a Dirac delta function.

The reason I am asking this question is because I am facing a third order equation with coefficients involving the Dirac delta function. I am able to find a solution but I would like to make my computations more mathematically sound.

Comment: You could interpret this potential as the limiting case of a finite square well potenital (width goes to zero and height goes to infinity the  area  width*heigth is required to stay finite). Then everything should be well defined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question on MathOverFlow and [Paul Garrett](https://mathoverflow.net/users/15629/paul-garrett) gave the answer I was looking for [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211701/make-mathematical-sense-of-the-dirac-well-potential-equation).